# open a url using java script for Ubiquity command

Tags: javascript, ubiquity

I was writting a [Ubiquity](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Ubiquity/Ubiquity_0.5_Author_Tutorial#Hello_World:_The_First_Command) command but I have 0 expriece on JS. How to open an url (http://www.stackoverflow.com for example ) using JS?

EDIT:

Thanks you all, I believe you are correct, but with following code I was not be able to jump to so. It might be something related with Ubiquity but It was declared to be JS.

```
CmdUtils.CreateCommand({
names: ["so"],
preview: "go to stackoverflow",

execute: function so_execute() {
     displayMessage("Hello, World!");
     window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'dialog');
    //neither other two method will work
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my english in advance)

I belive you're missing `Utils.openUrlInBrowser(URL-TO-OPEN)` or similar.

let me show you this code, open a new tab, with some content.

```
CmdUtils.CreateCommand({
  name: "bofh",
  preview: "Open a new tab with an BOFH excuse from The Bastard Operator From Hell-style excuse server..",
  execute: function(){
    Utils.openUrlInBrowser( "http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/bofhserver.pl" );
  }
})
```

HTH

Answer (score 6):

**1st method:**

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
```

**2nd method:**

```
window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
```

**3rd method:** (for new window/popup)

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'dialog');
```

Answer (score 1):

The following opens the given address in the current window.

```
 window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```